# Linux development: How to know what are the dependencies of my own program?

Tags: java, c, linux, packaging

I am pretty much still a beginner programmer. But I want to do Linux development. However all my college courses(except for the Java one) were Windows oriented. So we never had to do any packaging. But I want to package my programs for Linux(Deb and maybe RPM).

I wonder, are there any tools that scan my source code and suggest dependencies?

What would be the dependencies of a 'hello world' C program?
What would be the dependencies of a 'hello world' Java program?
Is there any tutorial for recognising your own dependencies?

Comment: I think you need to pick one language and learn about the package managers for it - to start you off you could look at Maven for Java

Comment: If you question is 'How do I learn what libraries are available for the language I am using?', then I'm afraid that just come with experience.  It isn't really a 'suggest' thing - more of a 'define'.

Comment: Are you trying to make an rpm or deb package:

Comment: 'suggest','define'?  On Linux, it' more of a 'prayer'.

Answer (score 1):

For compiled binaries, take a look at `ldd`. It shows file names for dynamic libraries used to load the executable. You'll need to use some sort of who-owns command of your package manager to find out which packages those libraries belong to.

```
> ldd hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff7b5fb000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa6b1d96000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa6b2137000)

> pacman -Qo /usr/lib/libc.so.6 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/lib/libc.so.6 is owned by glibc 2.23-2
/usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is owned by glibc 2.23-2
```

In this case, the only dependency is `glibc` package.

Note this way you will only find one particular kind of dependencies.
Without any of the libraries, your binaries won't start, but there may be additional dependencies which are not dynamic libraries. In particular, if the executable tries to open(), dlopen(), exec() or call system() on files from other packages, you won't see that in `ldd` output.

Even for libraries, `ldd` does not care about indirect dependencies, it just lists everything that got loaded. Using something like `readelf -d hello | grep NEEDED` may clarify things a bit.

Some package managers (RPM) do this kind of checks when making a package, and add all dependencies found. Others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would know your program's dependencies since you actively choose to `#include` a header from a library. If a header comes from a Debian package called `libfoo-dev`, then the runtime dependency would typically be `libfoo`. Additionally, you'd depend on executables you call using `system`/`execve` since they'd need to be installed on the system at runtime, in order to be run.

For Java, it's similar, in that you depend on any `jar` files you may add to your repository. If you use a build system such as Maven or Gradle, you would already have a set of dependencies that Maven/Gradle are aware of and fetch to make available to you at compile- and run-time. Similarly, any JNI libraries+bindings or executables you call using `ProcessBuilder` are also dependencies.